# TabeViewer alternate rows colors algorithm

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

i have implemented alternating rows color on my TableViewer, i have made some test with 30 000 rows :

without Color alternating i take 20 sec to load the table and 1 m 40 sec with colors alternating.

so my algorithm is not optimized for a table of this size,i would like to implement a méthode demonstrated in this [snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet041TableViewerAlternatingColors.java)

but it's not the same case, me i have extented ObservableMapLabelProvider (i have used a DataBinding,

```
public class CompteEntrysLabelProvider extends ObservableMapLabelProvider
    implements IColorProvider {

@Override
public Color getBackground(Object element) {

       WritableList list = new WritableList() ;
   list= (WritableList) this.tableViewer.getInput();

   int index = list.indexOf(element);

      if ((index % 2) == 0) {

        return gray; // color

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented my own method, what do you think about? I reduced the loading time of my TableViewer by half

We do not need to check the index value of element, which takes a few time, every time the column index is null (0) this implies that a new line begins, so we alternate the row color.

```
public class CompteEntrysLabelProvider extends ObservableMapLabelProvider
        implements IColorProvider {

private boolean isEven = true;

public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {

switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        isEven = !isEven; //toggle isEven value each first column

        //get column 3 text


    case 1:
        //get column 2 text

    case 2:
        //get column 3 text

    case 3:

         default: return "";

}

@Override
 public Color getBackground(Object element) {

    //based on IsEven value we alternate the row color  
       if (isEven) {  return gray;} else {return null;  }


   }

}
```

I hope it will help more than one